Two Generic Pnp Monitors in Device manager: how to tell which is which?
My device manager shows me two similarly titled "Generic Pnp Monitor".
I have a laptop and a Samsung g4 odyssey monitor connected to it.
The problem is when I tried installing driver for Samsung it asked me to choose between these two monitors. But I don't know which corresponds to laptop display and which to samsung because similarly to the Device Manager, installer shows same title (Generic Pnp Monitor) for both.
In device manager, I went into Properties->details ->Hardware Ids for each monitor, and one says "CMN14D5" the other says "SAM7275". Is it safe to assume the later is for my Samsung monitor?
I am assuming If I can at least tell the difference between the two in Device Manager, I should be able to tell, for which I installed the driver, and then install for a different if I chose the wrong one from Samsung installer.

The "SAM" is indeed a solid hint it might be the Samsung monitor, but you can be sure, because "CMN14D5" is the product code for a 14" laptop display panel. So that confirms the "SAM7275" device is your external monitor. NB Innolux is only the display panel brand, not that of your laptop. Many laptop brands use this display panel.
https://www.panelook.com/N140HCE-EN2_Innolux_14.0_LCM_overview_30961.html
